# DynamoDB - Query returning fewer results than Scan

Tags: javascript, typescript, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk-js

Really hoping someone can help me here because I'm out of ideas.

I've filled a database table with 4974 items, **all of which are deliberately the exact same record** i.e. all of type "car" and subtype "suv"

When I do a scan for all records, I get the full number of items back.
When I query for all the records (basically by saying startTime = 1, and endTime is a time after the last post) - I'm short on the results back (when they should be the same).

I have the following code:

database.ts:

```
public async fetchAllMessages(): Promise<
    DocumentClient.ItemList | undefined>
{
  let scanOutput: DocumentClient.ScanOutput;
  let scanResults: DocumentClient.ItemList = [];

  this.logger.log('Database fetchAllMessages');
  try {
    const query: DocumentClient.QueryInput = {
      TableName: this.tableName(),
      ReturnConsumedCapacity: 'INDEXES',
    };
    do {
      scanOutput = await this.documentClient.**scan**(query).promise();
      if (scanOutput.Items) {
        scanResults = scanResults.concat(scanOutput.Items);
        this.logRetrievedResults(scanOutput);
        query.ExclusiveStartKey = scanOutput.LastEvaluatedKey;
      }
    } while (typeof scanOutput.LastEvaluatedKey !== 'undefined');
  
    this.logger.log(
      `Database fetchAllMessages scanResults ${JSON.stringify(scanResults)}`,
    );
    return scanResults;
  } catch (exp) {
    this.logger.error(exp);
    throw exp;
  }
}
```

and:

```
 public async searchMessages(
    type?: string,
    subType?: string,
    startTime?: number,
    endTime?: number,
  ): Promise<DocumentClient.ItemList | undefined> {
    let queryOutput: DocumentClient.QueryOutput;
    let queryResults: DocumentClient.ItemList = [];
    
    this.logger.log(
      'Database searchMessages using params - type: ' +
        JSON.stringify(type) +
        ', subType: ' +
        JSON.stringify(subType) +
        ', startTime: ' +
        JSON.stringify(startTime) +
        ', endTime: ' +
        JSON.stringify(endTime),
    );
    try {
      const keyConditionExpression = generateKeyConditionExpression(
        type,
        subType,
        startTime,
        endTime,
      );
      const expressionAttributeNames = generateExpressionAttributeNamesMap(
        type,
        subType,
        startTime,
        endTime,
      );
      const expressionAttributeValues = generateExpressionAttributeValueMap(
        type,
        subType,
        startTime,
        endTime,
      );
      const filterExpression = generateFilterExpression(startTime, endTime);
      const query: DocumentClient.QueryInput = {
        TableName: this.tableName(),
        IndexName: this.TYPE_IDX,
        ReturnConsumedCapacity: 'INDEXES',
      };
      if (keyConditionExpression.length > 0) {
        query.KeyConditionExpression = keyConditionExpression;
      }
      if (Object.keys(expressionAttributeNames).length !== 0) {
        query.ExpressionAttributeNames = expressionAttributeNames;
      }
      if (Object.keys(expressionAttributeValues).length !== 0) {
        query.ExpressionAttributeValues = expressionAttributeValues;
      }
      if ((type || subType) && filterExpression.length > 0) {
        query.FilterExpression = filterExpression;
      }
      
      do {
        queryOutput = await this.documentClient.**query**(query).promise();
        if (queryOutput.Items) {
          queryResults = queryResults.concat(queryOutput.Items);
          this.logRetrievedResults(queryOutput);
          query.ExclusiveStartKey = queryOutput.LastEvaluatedKey;
        }
      } while (typeof queryOutput.LastEvaluatedKey !== 'undefined');
      return queryResults;
    } catch (exp) {
      this.logger.error(exp);
      throw exp;
    }
  }
```

message-helper.ts:

**edit: forgot this code block for messageType**

```
export function messageType(type?: string, subType?: string): string {
  let typeValue = '';
  if (type && subType) {
    typeValue = type + '_' + subType;
  } else if (type && !subType) {
    typeValue = type;
  } else if (!type && subType) {
    typeValue = subType;
  }

  return typeValue;
}

export function generateFilterExpression(
  startTime?: number,
  endTime?: number,
): string {
  logger.log(
    `Message-Helper startTime: ${toString(startTime)} 
      endTime: ${toString(endTime)}`,
  );
  let filterExpression = '';
  const BOTH_EXP = '#time BETWEEN :startTimeValue AND :endTimeValue';
  const START_EXP = '#time >= :startTimeValue';
  const END_EXP = '#time <= :endTimeValue';
  
  if ((startTime || startTime == 0) && (endTime || endTime == 0)) {
    filterExpression = BOTH_EXP;
  } else if ((startTime || startTime == 0) && !(endTime || endTime == 0)) {
    filterExpression = START_EXP;
  } else if (!(startTime || startTime == 0) && (endTime || endTime == 0)) {
    filterExpression = END_EXP;
  }
  
  logger.log('Message-Helper filterExpression', filterExpression);
  return filterExpression;
}

export function generateKeyConditionExpression(
  type?: string,
  subType?: string,
  startTime?: number,
  endTime?: number,
): string {
  logger.log(
    `Message-Helper startTime: ${toString(startTime)} 
      endTime: ${toString(endTime)}`,
  );
  let keyConditionExpression = '';
  const TYPE_EXP = '#columnName = :typeValue';
  const BOTH_EXP = '#time BETWEEN :startTimeValue AND :endTimeValue';
  const START_EXP = '#time >= :startTimeValue';
  const END_EXP = '#time <= :endTimeValue';
  
  if (type || subType) {
    keyConditionExpression = TYPE_EXP;
  } else if ((startTime || startTime == 0) && (endTime || endTime == 0)) {
    keyConditionExpression = BOTH_EXP;
  } else if ((startTime || startTime == 0) && !(endTime || endTime == 0)) {
    keyConditionExpression = START_EXP;
  } else if (!(startTime || startTime == 0) && (endTime || endTime == 0)) {
    keyConditionExpression = END_EXP;
  }
  
  logger.log('Message-Helper keyConditionExpression', keyConditionExpression);
  return keyConditionExpression;
}

export function generateExpressionAttributeValueMap(
  type?: string,
  subType?: string,
  startTime?: number,
  endTime?: number,
): DocumentClient.ExpressionAttributeValueMap {
  const expressionAttributeValueMap: DocumentClient.ExpressionAttributeValueMap = {};
  
  if (type || subType) {
    expressionAttributeValueMap[':typeValue'] = messageType(type, subType);
    if ((startTime || startTime == 0) && (endTime || endTime == 0)) {
      logger.log(
        'Message-Helper generateExpressionAttributeValueMap all values',
      );
      expressionAttributeValueMap[':startTimeValue'] = startTime;
      expressionAttributeValueMap[':endTimeValue'] = endTime;
    } else if ((startTime || startTime == 0) && !(endTime || endTime == 0)) {
      logger.log('Message-Helper generateExpressionAttributeValueMap no end');
      expressionAttributeValueMap[':startTimeValue'] = startTime;
    } else if (!(startTime || startTime == 0) && (endTime || endTime == 0)) {
      logger.log('Message-Helper generateExpressionAttributeValueMap no start');
      expressionAttributeValueMap[':endTimeValue'] = endTime;
    }
  } else {
    if ((startTime || startTime == 0) && (endTime || endTime == 0)) {
      logger.log('Message-Helper generateExpressionAttributeValueMap no type');
      expressionAttributeValueMap[':startTimeValue'] = startTime;
      expressionAttributeValueMap[':endTimeValue'] = endTime;
    } else if ((startTime || startTime == 0) && !(endTime || endTime == 0)) {
      logger.log(
        'Message-Helper generateExpressionAttributeValueMap only start',
      );
      expressionAttributeValueMap[':startTimeValue'] = startTime;
    } else if (!(startTime || startTime == 0) && (endTime || endTime == 0)) {
      logger.log('Message-Helper generateExpressionAttributeValueMap only end');
      expressionAttributeValueMap[':endTimeValue'] = endTime;
    }
  }
  
  return expressionAttributeValueMap;
}

export function generateExpressionAttributeNamesMap(
  type?: string,
  subType?: string,
  startTime?: number,
  endTime?: number,
): DocumentClient.ExpressionAttributeNameMap {
  const expressionAttributeNameMap: DocumentClient.ExpressionAttributeNameMap = {};
  if (type || subType) {
    logger.log(
      'Message-Helper generateExpressionAttributeNamesMap #columnName set',
    );
    expressionAttributeNameMap['#columnName'] = 'type';
  }
  if (startTime || startTime == 0 || endTime || endTime == 0) {
    logger.log('Message-Helper generateExpressionAttributeNamesMap time set');
    expressionAttributeNameMap['#time'] = 'CreationTime';
  }
  return expressionAttributeNameMap;
}
```

When I do fetchAllMessages, I get back the items, across 3 indexes, as logged on CloudWatch:

```
[Nest][Database] {"ScannedCount":1932,"Count":1932,"ItemsLength":1932,"LastEvaluatedKey":{"id":"fe13d459-329f-44bb-b456-ab0de9a515ee"... "ConsumedCapacity": {"TableName": "analytics","CapacityUnits": 128,"Table": {"CapacityUnits": 128}}}

[Nest][Database] {"ScannedCount":1932,"Count":1932,"ItemsLength":1932,"LastEvaluatedKey":{"id":"22f1c6f0-9e52-4836-a92e-6ad3f87f7281"... "ConsumedCapacity": {"TableName": "analytics","CapacityUnits": 128,"Table": {"CapacityUnits": 128}}}

[Nest][Database] {"ScannedCount":1110,"Count":1110,"ItemsLength":1110," "ConsumedCapacity": {"TableName": "analytics","CapacityUnits": 73.5,"Table": {"CapacityUnits": 73.5}}}
```

Which is good!

But when I do searchMessages, searching for the type, subtype, a startTime of 1 (the beginning of time), endTime (now) - e.g. **my-api-/search?type=car&subtype=suv&startTime=1&endTime=1652285721230&x-api-key=-mykey-** I get the following back:

```
[Nest][Database] {"ScannedCount":1802,"Count":1802,"ItemsLength":1802,"LastEvaluatedKey":{"id":"5d0e2da1-f00f-4af6-a824-0684855d0a41"..."ConsumedCapacity":{"TableName":"analytics","CapacityUnits":121,"Table":{"CapacityUnits":0},"GlobalSecondaryIndexes":{"typeIdx":{"CapacityUnits":121}}}}

[Nest][Database] {"ScannedCount":1802,"Count":1802,"ItemsLength":1802,"LastEvaluatedKey":{"id":"c32ca6e6-b06b-4393-8a8d-83f6a19e7813",..."ConsumedCapacity":{"TableName":"analytics","CapacityUnits":121,"Table":{"CapacityUnits":0},"GlobalSecondaryIndexes":{"typeIdx":{"CapacityUnits":121}}}}

[Nest][Database] {"ScannedCount":1103,"Count":1103,"ItemsLength":1103,"ConsumedCapacity":{"TableName":"analytics","CapacityUnits":74,"Table":{"CapacityUnits":0},"GlobalSecondaryIndexes":{"typeIdx":{"CapacityUnits":74}}}}
```

The count metrics from searchMessages are adding up to ~200 less than for the fetchAllMessages version.

I don't understand why this is.

I'd really appreciate some help because not all of this is my code, so I'm having trouble understanding a lot of it - but I do know that at the time, certain factors weren't considered (for example it was me who added the do-while for the pagination edge-case)

Your help would be greatly appreciated - I'm really lost!

Edit:for yourself, jarmod,
[image]

Comment: I would first go and run the scan and the (correct) query using the awscli to check that the number of returned items is the same in both responses. If they are not the same, then the issue is not your query but that some of the items in the table aren't captured by your query. BTW you say that all of these items are "the exact same record" but they can't be. What are the partition and sort key attribute names in your table?

Comment: What happens if you query the secondary index with no filter? Does it return the same number of items as the table scan, or fewer? If fewer, then some of the items in the table are not in the index which suggests that some of the table's items do not have the indexed attributes.

Comment: As an aside, you might want to consider using a DynamoDB wrapper library such as [dynamoose](https://dynamoosejs.com) which would simplify your code significantly and improve its readability. See [conditions](https://dynamoosejs.com/guide/Condition) for examples of its filter condition support.

Comment: Hi jarmod, thanks for your replies! 
"id" is my partition key, and "message" is my sort key, message being the body composed of "type" and a nested "type" which is referred to as "subtype" when querying.

edit: have shared additional code above (message-handler.ts code).. I had overlooked it when choosing which code to share

I wasn't able to query to GSI, can you help me figure that one out?
(see image added to OP)

Comment: Not sure what your question is. You're already issuing a query against `IndexName: this.TYPE_IDX`. I'm suggesting that you issue this query with no filter so that you get all items in the index returned. If the number of items returned doesn't match what you get from the scan then your data may be incorrect (and your query can never return the same number of items as the scan).

Comment: when I go to my table in DynamoDB on the AWS Console, and go to Indexes tab, it provides me with the following:

`Name: typeIdx` 
`Status: Active`
`Partition Key: type (String)`
`Sort key: message (String)`
`Read capacity: 1 | Auto scaling is off`
`Write capacity: 1 | Auto scaling is off`
`Projected attributes: Include: CreationTime, type`
`Size: 1.5 megabytes`
`Item count: 4,974`

the item count is the same as the live count / the count logged for fetchAllMessages (scan)
but not what gets logged for searchMessages on C'Watch


**Is that the same as querying without a filter?**

Comment: I suspect that some of the items in the index aren't being returned by your query filter. If you invert the filter and re-run, it should return the list of items that do *not* match the filter. Debug those items to see why they don't match the original filter.

Comment: thanks for the advice jarmod, as you can probably tell - I'm not very good at this. How can I invert the query? So far I've been querying it via `my-api-/search?type=car&subtype=suv&startTime=1&endTime=1652285721230&x-api-key=-mykey-` on Postman

Comment: Your filter is presumably a series of ANDed terms e.g. type=A AND subtype=B AND startTIme>=C AND endTime<=D so manually issue a query that filters type<>A OR subtype<>B OR startTime<C OR endTime>D.